# Mongo/Node update data by productID from foreign JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

How can I please change the data from foreign `JSON`? I need to update products in my database just "count" and "price" on `Node.js` (express) with `MongoDB`(atlas).

I will fetch the data from API and then? Thanks

Example of data:

My data

```
{  "_id": "1200003270",
   "productid: "147853",
    "count": 223,
    "price: 14"
}

{
 "_id": "1200003250",
 "productid": "54533"
   "count": "91,
    "price: "143"
}
```

`JSON` from foreign `API`

```
{  "productid": "147853"
   "count": 141,
    "price: 9"
}

{  "productid": "54533"
   "count": "91,
    "price: "143"
}
```

Comment: What did you do? `db.products.update({productid: '147853'}, {$set: {"count": 141, "price: 9"}})` . https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: Thanks.. I need just every 24 hours make update of database from one external company CMS on my ecommerce... problem is im just focused on front end and i know just small about backend... Will this work if i want make this for example 400 products on one time? i will get always json with 400 products..  should i make first object and them put like variable in ({productid: 'myobject'} ??